# Using regex assertion in python

Tags: python, regex

I am experimenting with regex and i have read up on assertions a bit and seen examples but for some reason I can not get this to work.. I am trying to get the word after the following pattern using look-behind.

```
import re
s = '123abc456someword 0001abde19999anotherword'
re.findall(r'(?<=\d+[a-z]+\d+)[a-z]+', s, re.I)
```

The results should be `someword` and `anotherword`

But i get `error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's as it says; it's expects you to give input for a fixed width of the characters, and not a dynamic one. Try using `{#}` instead of `? + *` etc.

Comment: it's clear from the error that look-behind requires fixed-width pattern.

Comment: I see that in the documentation as I read it now..

Comment: Now look at the solutions.

Comment: So you can't use * or + in lookbehind?

Comment: @Jackson: and ? or {m,n} too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it to [Non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and get the matched group from index 1.

```
(?:\d+\w+\d+)(\w+\b)
```

here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bT2oQ2/2)

If you are interested in `[a-z]` only then change `\w` to `[a-z]` in above regex pattern. Here `\b` is added to assert position at a word boundary.

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?:\d+\w+\d+)(\w+\b)', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"123abc456someword 0001abde19999anotherword"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 4):

Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module only allows **fixed-length** strings using look-behinds. If you want to experiment and be able to use variable length look-behinds in regexes, use the alternative [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = '123abc456someword 0001abde19999anotherword'
>>> regex.findall(r'(?i)(?<=\d+[a-z]+\d+)[a-z]+', s)
['someword', 'anotherword']
```

Or simply avoid using look-behind in general and use a capturing group `( )`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '123abc456someword 0001abde19999anotherword'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+[a-z]+\d+([a-z]+)', s, re.I)
['someword', 'anotherword']
```

Comment: I didn't know there was a regex module, so you can do this using it? I will have to try and install this module and play around with it.

Comment: +1 for the fabulous `regex` module (and the capture group alternative which is the general solutions for engines without lookbehind) :)

Answer (score 0):

Another easy method through **lookahead**,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '123abc456someword 0001abde19999anotherword'
>>> m = re.findall(r'[a-z]+(?= |$)', s, re.I)
>>> m
['someword', 'anotherword']
```

It matches one or more alphabets in which the following character must be a space  or end of a line.